# Open pdf file in pdf viewer using unity android above api 23

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-container

I am trying to open a pdf file using this:

```
Application.OpenUrl("file://" + path)
```

This line code open in less than 23 API supported devices, but it doesn't support above API 23 supported devices.

Comment: also try by :- Process.Start("file://" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "Certificate" + this.value + ".pdf");

Comment: and also try by: - <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/fileprovider" />
        </provider>

Comment: can you provide any reason why you don't want to make your target to api 23